# memoir: chapter style: recapitulation

Tags: memoir, chapters

What is the right way to make chapter recapitulations (or is there the proper way to call it?) old fashioned style, like in *Gulliver's Travels*?

PART I--A VOYAGE TO LILLIPUT.
1. CHAPTER I.
[The author gives some account of himself and family. His first inducements to travel. He is shipwrecked, and swims for his life. Gets safe on shore in the country of Lilliput; is made a prisoner, and carried up the country.]

My father had a small estate in Nottinghamshire: I was the third of five sons. He sent me to Emanuel College in Cambridge at fourteen years old, where I resided three years, and applied myself close to my studies;

I mean the part inside brackets. I suppose you remember how it looks on paper :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [did](https://epub.uni-bayreuth.de/3774/) it. The name is chapter precis.

```
\chapter{Feature-Based Multi-Resolution Registration of Immunostained Serial Sections}
\label{cha:media16}
\chapterprecishere{In which we discuss the fine-grain registration of
  serial sections and its quality. We are able to register the serial
  sections up to smallest capillaries, despite a lot of
  self-similarity.}
% ...
```

There is also an option to state some precis for the TOC, `\chapterprecistoc`. The `\chapterprecis` command does both.

*Update:* It looks like this. I took a different chapter such that the precis is small enough.

[image: screenshot of a document with chapter precis]

Comment: I like your graphic. Further information on `\chapterprecis` and friends is in section **6.5.8 Chapter precis** of the manual (`> texdoc memoir`).